# Unable to reduce the dropdown height

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using "select" dropdown ie "Basic Select" from https://mui.com/components/selects/#basic-select, but the height of the dropdown is more than required,

how to reduce the height of the dropdown?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';

export default function BasicSelect() {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState('');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={age}
          label="Age"
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

I have tried passing `<FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120, padding: 0 }}>` but did not work.

when I change 'padding' in dev tools, height has reduced, but not sure how to apply in this component code.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use the [MenuProps](https://mui.com/api/select/) of the `Select` component to control the styling of the Menu. [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicselect-material-demo-forked-wlu7z?file=/demo.js)

Comment: @JunaidFaryad it did not work. ` <Select
          value={material}
          onChange={handleChange}
          displayEmpty
          inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Without label" }}
          MenuProps={{
            sx: {
              height: 10,
              padding:0
            }
          }}`

Comment: What is your material ui version?

Comment: Do you want to reduce the height of the `input field`, which controls the select toggle functionality?

Comment: I want to reduce the height of entire dropdown, as shown at this link https://mui.com/components/selects/#basic-select and also, I am uploading image of the same. pls check.

Comment: Thanks. Checkout the updated [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicselect-material-demo-forked-wlu7z?file=/demo.js), which is applying styles using class of the select component.

Comment: @JunaidFaryad It worked now. your updated example is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';

export default function BasicSelect() {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState('');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={age}
          label="Age"
          onChange={handleChange}
          sx={{
             "& .MuiSelect-select": {
               paddingTop: 0.5,
               paddingBottom: 0.5,
           },
      }}
        >
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Following @JunaidFaryad answer, I got the working code as above.